# How do python programmers deal with inability to use reserved keywords as names for variables in python (like`from`)?

Tags: python

I want to use name `from` for an argument of a function. But `from` is a reserved keyword, so python will throw an exception if I decide to use this name for a variable.
How programmers in python deal with it? I think `from` is a common name for variables, in python as well. Is there any standards in python for how to rename the argument/variable in this case? Do they use prefixes/suffixes like `from_`?

Comment: Yes, that's what they do.

Comment: prefixing or suffixing the variable should prevent it from being a keyword, but _ prefixed variables are supposed to be "private" in the scope of the class/package they exist in. Ideally, you just add more to the name. instead of "from", make it "fromList" or "fromTable" or whatever context the variable comes from. This will add readability to the code as well

Comment: I wonder if the ability to add soft keywords to the grammar will mean that someday `from` will be allowed as an identifier. (As far as I know, no existing keywords have been converted to soft keywords, only new keywords like `match` and `case`.)

Comment: Prefix and suffix have different meanings, by convention. Use an underscore suffix to avoid shadowing another var name, builtin or keyword, whereas underscore prefix indicates private var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many languages have these challenges. Some ideas:

- As mentioned in the comments, tack an underscore on the end: `from_`
- Add context or type (also mentioned in comments): `from` => `from_list`
- Mangle the spelling (`from` => `frm`, e.g. `class` => `klass` or `cls`)
- Use a synonym: `from` => `source`

Each approach has its advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

**Essentially yes**, prefixes and suffixes are added to change the text from a reserved keyword to a user defined variable.

The example you used could be changed to something like `fromJob`, `fromPerson`, or `from_order`.
Officially, function variables should use underscores as separators instead of camelCase. Ex. `from_here` or `from_there_and_here`

[PEP 8: Function and Variable Names](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names):

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
> underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.
>
> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the
> prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards
> compatibility.

Prefixing a variable from `var1` to `_var1` is recognized to be an internal or private variable within a module or class and should be avoided in a general function. Credit @smcrowley

Hope this helps!